# Check if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n \sqrt[n]{n}} $ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

> Check if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n \sqrt[n]{n}}$ converges

I've tried using the Cauchy test and the root test but none of them seems to work with this series and so  I decided to apply the comparison test.  
I don't know if what I'm doing right now is correct:  
It is know that $$\sqrt[n]n \rightarrow1$$ And so if we take sufficiently large n, $n \sqrt[n]{n} < 2n$ Which implies that
$$\mbox{For sufficiently large n} \\\frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]n}>\frac 1 {2n}$$
And so now, by the virtue of the comparison test, I can claim that the series in question diverges. Is it a correct way to do this? If so, is it possible to pick any positive integer greater than $2$ instead of $2$ for this method to work?

Comment: Perfect.${{{}}}$

Comment: Your reasoning is sound.  Remember to always include the summation symbol when discussing a series (I've taken the liberty of putting this in for you).  If you write the bald term like "$\frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}$" by itself, you're talking about a sequence.  That might introduce ambiguity because the sequence converges, while the associated series does not.

Comment: Yes, any real number bigger than 1 will work (such as $1.001$, or $42$), since $n^{1/n}$ will be less than that number for all sufficiently large $n$.  The number 2 is a convenient choice.